# Featured image always rendered with 198px of height?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I added the following to my **functions.php** file:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 500, 500);
```

I enabled **featured image** (`support => 'thumbnail'`) in a custom post type a created (called Page Content).

When I set an image as featured image (the image I'm using has **500px** of height) , the image is always rendered with 198px of height.

**EDIT:**

It renders 198px in final page and 117px in the admin panel.

This is the code of the final output:

```
<img class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="448" height="198" title="2974999772_7085da4d34" alt="2974999772_7085da4d34" src="http://localhost/wp-alex-chen/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/2974999772_7085da4d344-448x198.jpg
```

This is the code of the featured image in the admin panel:

```
<img width="266" height="117" title="2974999772_7085da4d34" alt="2974999772_7085da4d34" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" src="http://localhost/wp-alex-chen/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/2974999772_7085da4d344-448x198.jpg">
```

Edit Post panel:

[image]

Any suggestions to solve this? (the 'normal' Posts have also the same problem (height= 198px)

**EDIT2: I aded this to functions.php:**

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'thumb-1', 320, 280, true );
}
```

It is set to have hard-crop but the image is rendered as 250px 280px (it should render as 320px x 280px).

Comment: @janoChen - *Where* is it always rendered 428px x 198px? What does the code look like that renders it?  *(Details are your friend.)*

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I added that in the EDIT.

Comment: @jano: Please post that images original pixel size and aspect ratio. Then compare that with your thumbnail images aspect ratio. IIRC wordpress will always use the smallest size of any side not to cut stuff away.

Comment: @janoChen - Not sure I know how to fix this without seeing your system. Maybe someone else can solve it.

Comment: @hakre the original picture is 280px x 320px, for some reason Wordpress is now making it 280px x 280px. Even if I'm using this:  `add_image_size( 'thumb-1', 320, 280, true );`

Comment: What code do you use in template to display image? There are a **lot** of functions related to this functionality and it is hard to step through without specific function calls you make.

Comment: @Rarst I used this: `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using a child theme of TwentyTen and in TwentyTen theme you have this line:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH, HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT, true );
```

and HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT is 198px.

Comment: commenting out this code fixed this issue for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `<?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>` instead of `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` fixed the problem.

`<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` seems to have a very weird default setting for resizing thumbnails.

Comment: [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) in Codex has note about crop not working somehow with it. I am not sure about specifics but I think that is likely what caused your issues.

Comment: @Rarst: I'm smelling the same, I wish Jan could add two cents, he probably knows best.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after inspecting  a little bit how wordpress is generating the html for the featured image I found with **editor_max_image_size** in [wp-includes/media.php](http://phpxref.com/xref/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php.source.html) **on line 76** the decisive filter to hook in.

At first, of course, you have to setup your individual image size as usual in your **function.php**, for example i want a post-thumbnail size 600px x 400px:

```
function abc_set_size() {
   add_image_size( 'post-thumbnail', 600, 400, true );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'abc_set_size' );
```

Wordpress wants to use this dimension for the featured image (which was setup in the theme) inside the backend but rollback to a standard size with this filter in line 76. The filter hook has 3 parameters to differentiate which image should be 'tuned' in his dimension:

```
function abc_my_editor_size($size_array,$size,$context) {
   global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

   if($size == 'post-thumbnail' && $context == 'edit')
       return array( 
          $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$size]['width'],    
          $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$size]['height'] );

   return $size_array;
}
add_filter('editor_max_image_size', 'abc_my_editor_size', 10, 3);
```

Just like wanted, only the image dimension for the featured image inside the admin backend is edited. I use the global array `$_wp_additional_image_sizes` to have access to the my setted image dimension for a post-thumbnail.

Works fine for me, i would recommenend it ! Any thoughts about this ?